# Custom validator on asp page returns Page.IsValid (ture) even when invalid entry

Tags: asp.net, validation, email-validation

I have a piece of code which i need to fix.

```
<td>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxCss"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqEmail" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail"
        ErrorMessage="Enter Email" ValidationGroup="entryvalid" Display="None">  
   </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
   <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender4" runat="server" 
        TargetControlID="reqEmail"  CssClass="CustomValidator" />
   <asp:CustomValidator ID="valEmail" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" Display="None"
        runat="server" ValidationGroup="entryvalid" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Address"
        ClientValidationFunction="ValidateEmail" />
   <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender3" runat="server" 
        TargetControlID="valEmail" CssClass="CustomValidator" />
</td>
```

If i am leaving email box empty then it says "enter mail" and page.IsValid is returning **False** using the below code:

```
public bool IsValid
{
   get
    {
     EnableValidation(true);
     Page.Validate("entryvalid");                
     return Page.IsValid;
    }
}
```

EmailValidation func :

```
function ValidateEmail(source, arguments) {
    var val1 = $.trim(arguments.Value.toLowerCase());
    var regexemail = /^([\w-_]+\.)*[\w-_]+@([\w-_]+\.)*[\w-_]+\.[\w-_]+$/;
    arguments.IsValid = regexemail.test(val1);
}
```

But when i give invalid email ("user@gmail@.com") it says "Invalid Entry" but Page.IsValid is returning **True**.
Can anyone please mention where might be wrong?

Comment: Can you post the code for your email validation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this for email validation:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="valEmail" runat="server" 
  ErrorMessage="* Please enter a valid email address" 
  ControlToValidate="txtEmail"
  ValidationGroup="Group1" 
  ValidationExpression="^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

This is client side validation rather than server side validation

**EDIT**

Currently the server does not know if the custom validator is valid or not.

You need to add: `OnServerValidate="ServerValidation"` to the custom validator in the aspx.

Then add the following server side:

```
void ServerValidation (object source, ServerValidateEventArgs arguments)
{
  //perform your check here.
  arguments.IsValid = false;
}
```

Now when `Page.IsValid` is called, the server will know about the custom validator.

See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: actually email validation is correct, its giving "invalid email" ( args.IsValid = false) but Page.IsValid is giving ture.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Aspx code:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvEmail" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtEmail"
                            InitialValue="" ValidationGroup="SubscriptionDetails" ErrorMessage="Email is Mandatory"
                            ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vceEmail" TargetControlID="rfvEmail" runat="server">
                        </ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexEmailValid" runat="server" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$"
                            ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email" ValidationGroup="SubscriptionDetails"
                            Display="None"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vce1Email" TargetControlID="regexEmailValid"
                            runat="server">
                        </ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
```

Comment: thnx but i dont have ajaxtoolkit in my project. can't we do it without it..ofcourse i can download it but client would'nt allow.

Comment: but u can use the asp validatorcalloutextender insteadof the ajax